# Restrict cores for multiprocessing in Tesseract

Tags: python, redis, tesseract, python-tesseract

[image of running process status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPFKr.png)

I am trying to implement multiprocessing with redis queue. The job inserted in the queue is tesseract ocr process on a file having 11 pages, taking approx. 70 sec.
I started 2 workers and inserted 2 jobs inside redis queue, which were fetched by workers respectively.

Expected output: Both workers should execute tesseract simultaneously on respective files.

Current Output: Switching is happening between the jobs. At one time, 1 image is getting processed inside first worker and then image of another file is processed on another worker. So, both workers are giving output at same time after 140 seconds.

How do i restrict the Tesseract process to use only half of the cpu cores so that both process can run simultaneously.

Technology used: Python, Pytesseract, Redis queue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the technologies mentioned but it sounds more like you have multiple threads, not multiprocessing. You can see if there is an option to create a process pool.

Comment: i think multi processing is already happening, because i checked status of running process and found two instances of tesseract, but one time only one file is getting processed and then switching happens to process another file.